# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras, искусственный-интеллект

Я новичок в ML и Keras. Пытаюсь построить модель

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_shape=X_train.shape))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Но при попытке запустить `model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=1)` вылетает

> `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2`

PS. [полный текст программы](https://pastebin.com/ZR9DaBvM)

PS2. Знаю про [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44583254/valueerror-input-0-is-incompatible-with-layer-lstm-13-expected-ndim-3-found-n) вопрос, но решение не помогло.

PS3. [файл данных](https://www.dropbox.com/s/biyczttoqj7b8qq/data.txt?dl=0)

Comment: @MaxU обновил вопрос

Comment: Можете пояснить формат данных в файле? И как вы планируете обучать НС если у вас всего один класс (все нули) в выходном векторе `Y_train`?

Comment: @MaxU пока-что никак не планирую обучать - собираю данные. [формат данных](https://pastebin.com/Tk4DLqNM)